# How to view pending messages in RabbitMQ admin?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

How do you view pending/queued messages in RabbitMQ admin?

I have the RabbitMQ admin tool running, and the overview page is showing that there are over 4000 messages ready. It's also showing that there are over 90 consumers. Yet the number of ready messages isn't changing, and my Celery processors aren't reporting that they're processing any tasks.

How do I view the actual messages that are queued in Rabbit? None of the pages in admin seem to show you messages. Clicking under Queues shows me the queues with the most ready messages, but clicking into one of those queues again doesn't show any messages.

Also, I've configured Celery to run 2 processes, 1 to consume queue "default" and one to consume queue "long", for 10 different client applications. So I would expect there to be 2*10 = 20 queues listed in RabbitMQ, yet it's listing over 100 with random names like "f5e18f4a079045cbafbca48fb20c7cec", and none of them appear to be getting worked on. What are all these junk queues?